# Assert method in Webmethod asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pagemethods, webmethod

I've a web method that has been called up using page methods. Assert function is not working in it although condition fails.

**I want to test at what condition my code fails and debug it as in Assert menthod.**

How should i debug that web menthod. Please suggest.

JavaScript Code

```
function sendingRqstForDealerCard(Argument) {

PageMethods.DealerTurn(OnSuccess);
function OnSuccess(response) {

    Sys.Debug.assert(response!="", "respone is blanck in DealerTurn Function");
}
```

javascript assert is working but i have to check code in code behind.

**Code Behind**

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string DealerTurn()
 {    
 string previousRowHandTotal = BLHand.GetHandTotalField(hand, Convert.ToUInt16(dealerSpotID));

   System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(previousRowHandTotal != string.Empty,"previousRowHandTotal is empty in dealerTurn function."); 
}
```

**Is there other way to debug WebMethod?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to provide the code for a fuller answer, however keep in mind that if you are using `Debug.Assert` and not running in Debug mode, then the Assert is not even compiled into the code. That could be the reason your assert is not triggering.

[Here is a MSDN article on how to run in debug mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243172.aspx). Typically, if you are running from visual studio, then this should prompt you to change the settings, though

Comment: Are you running in Debug mode, though? Are you expecting this to work in release code? Then you will want to use `Trace.Assert`. Or, maybe you really want to throw an exception?

Comment: Yes I am running in Debug mode.

Comment: I dont know that there is much more I can do here. Have you attached a debugger directly and verified that the `previousRowHandTotal` is String.Empty?